# Spring Boot API taking a long time with AWS RDS MySQL (With Entities with One-Many relationship)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds

Spring Boot API taking a long time with AWS RDS MySQL (With Entities with One-Many relationship)

Problem: **Updates/Inserts** of the order above 100-150 are happening as Parents can have more than **100-150 child records**.

- When we try to run my SQL application locally it works perfectly and
  return records in few milliseconds.
- In contrast to when we connect to AWS RDS, it takes 5-10 seconds.

Where shall I look for performance improvements?

Is this because of a Network delay and how can I check the same?

Stack: Spring boot, AWS RDS(MySQL), SpringDataJPA.

*DB Instance Used: db.r5.large**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Multi-region calls, from West to East us regions.

We check the host from where the call was going and as a DB writer Instance was only in one region it was taking long for these queries.